# How to make an if statement run for the entire For loop execution without going to else statement?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, for-loop

Continued from the question it seems
My code always outputs the else statement even when the if statement is true, i have assumed it is because the for loop is not getting executing completely before being denied that `input.value` is not available in `data[i].s`, therefore the output is always "I dont understand" even when `input.value = "hi"`

How to solve this?

```js
function senda() {

  var input = document.querySelector('input'),
    send = document.createElement('p'),
    recv = send.cloneNode(true),
    data = [{
      "s": "hi",
      "r": "hello"
    }, {
      "s": "whats up",
      "r": "alright"
    }];

  send.innerText = input.value;
  document.body.appendChild(send);
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (input.value == data[i].s) {
      recv.innerText = data[i].r;
      document.body.appendChild(recv);
    } else {
      recv.innerText = "I don't understand";
      document.body.appendChild(recv);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input>
<button onclick="senda()">-></button>
```

Comment: If `input.value` is `hi`, then output will be `hi` and `I don't understand`. Because there are two elements in an array and value will be checked two times.

Comment: Code is working as expected, what else do you want?

Comment: I think there's a fundamental flaw in your logic: if you want to check if the `input.value` matches **any** text in your code, then you want to break out of the for loop.

Comment: Can you provide a better logic such that For example, input is "hi" - output will be "hello" from the data and  if input is not available in data - output will be "not understand"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that your `for` loop will keep running for all entries in your `data` array. That means that even if a match is found, the loop continues to run, which causes the innerText to be replaced until the last item.

There is a simply way to do this: all you want is to check whether the user input matches *any* value in the nested `s` key in the array of object. You can use [`Array.prototype.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to retrieve the index that matches your requirement.

If the index is more than `-1`, then you know you have a match. Otherwise you can just return the fallback statement, e.g.:

```
const foundIndex = data.findIndex(d => d.s === input.value);
if (foundIndex > -1) {
  recv.innerText = data[foundIndex].r;
} else {
  recv.innerText = "I don't understand";
}
      
document.body.appendChild(recv);
```

For simplicity, you can condense this into a one-liner:

```
const foundIndex = data.findIndex(d => d.s === input.value);
recv.innerText = foundIndex > -1 ? data[foundIndex].r : "I don't understand";
```

Of course, this solution works only if the nested `s` values are unique in your array. Otherwise you will always get the first occurring matching instance.

There are some additional tips:

- Don't use inline JS bindings. Use `addEventListener` instead
- You might want to convert `input.value` to lowercase so that we can perform a case-insensitive match
- Store your `data` outside of the function: it is a constant and don't have to be redeclared every time the function is invoked

See proof-of-concept below with additional tips applied:

```js
const data = [{
  "s": "hi",
  "r": "hello"
}, {
  "s": "whats up",
  "r": "alright"
}];

function senda() {
  const input = document.querySelector('input');
  const send = document.createElement('p');
  const recv = send.cloneNode(true);

  send.innerText = input.value;
  document.body.appendChild(send);

  const foundIndex = data.findIndex(d => d.s.toLowerCase() === input.value.toLowerCase());
  recv.innerText = foundIndex > -1 ? data[foundIndex].r : "I don't understand";

  document.body.appendChild(recv);
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', senda);
```

```html
<input>
<button>-></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add one line code.

When the input vale is equal to data[i].s please add "i = data.length;"

```js
function senda() {
    var input = document.querySelector('input'),
        send = document.createElement('p'),
        recv = send.cloneNode(true),
        data = [{
            "s": "hi",
            "r": "hello"
        }, {
            "s": "whats up",
            "r": "alright"
        }];

    send.innerText = input.value;
    document.body.appendChild(send);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (input.value === data[i].s) {
            recv.innerText = data[i].r;
            document.body.appendChild(recv);
            i = data.length;
        } else {
            recv.innerText = "I don't understand";
            document.body.appendChild(recv);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input>
<button onclick="senda()">-></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine.

But it is not working as you thinking.

data has `2 obejct`:
And first loop

if it equals to `hi` and prints `hello` not works **else statement**

and second loop it is not equal to `hi` so this time `else statement` works

so you must break if it finds equal value

like below

```js
    function senda() {

      var input = document.querySelector('input'),
        send = document.createElement('p'),
        recv = send.cloneNode(true),
        data = [{
          "s": "hi",
          "r": "hello"
        }, {
          "s": "whats up",
          "r": "alright"
        }];

      send.innerText = input.value;
      document.body.appendChild(send);
      var isInputInData = false;
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (input.value == data[i].s) {
          recv.innerText = data[i].r;
          isInputInData = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if(!isInputInData) recv.innerText = "I don't understand";

      document.body.appendChild(recv);
    }
```

```html
  <input>
  <button onclick="senda()">-></button>
```